# Designing a push-pull amplifier

Tags: amplifier, resistors, design, push-pull

The exercise is to calculate \$ R_1\$, \$ R_2\$ and the gain for small signs of the following circuit, which is supposed to be a audio amplifier:

[image: Push pull circuit]

And I have the following information:

- \$ R_L = 8\Omega \$
- \$ \beta = 120\$
- \$ V_{BE} = V_{D_{ON}} = 0.7V\$
- \$ I_C = 40mA\$
- \$ I_D = 10 I_B\$
- \$ V_{CC} = 5V\$
- Transistors are 2N2222 and 2N2907

I am struggling to understand how to calculate these things, I did for a class A amplifier, that the gain is \$ \frac{R_L}{\frac{1}{g_m} + R_L} \$, but I didn't found some equation for this circuit. If anyone could explain especially how to calculate these resistors so I could design this in a simulator and study the behavior of the push and pull amplifier would help a lot.

So I did as jonk suggested and this is the result:

- \$I_B = \frac{I_C}{\beta} = \frac{1}{3000}A \$
- \$I_D = 10I_B = \frac{1}{300}A \$
- \$V_{CC} - 2V_{D_{ON}} = 3.6V \$
- \$ \frac{3.6V}{\frac{1}{300}} = 1080\Omega \$
- \$ R_1 + R_2 = 1080\Omega\$
- \$ R_1 = R_2 = 540\Omega \$

I imagined that these resistors would have the same value, but I am confused, could anyone explain if there is anything wrong?

Comment: The whole stage is mostly useless except as a teaching aid. You have no input peak-to-peak voltage specification. So this means you also have no output peak-to-peak voltage specification. So we can take both as ***small***. There's no frequency specification and if I were being ornery I'd set the frequency to DC. That said, they do specify \$I_{_\text{C}}\$, so you should be able to work backwards to the base current, use that to work out their diode currents and from that the resistor values. What part of that is difficult? Are you mostly just worried about the voltage gain (close to 1?)

Comment: Are you still stuck??? Just take the collector current, divide it by the beta to work out the base current, then multiply that by ten to get the diode current, and then take your supply voltage and subtract the two diode voltages from it and then divide into that the diode current to work out the total resistance. Cut that in half and your have your resistor values.

Comment: We are NOT taking any classes with you and have no idea what the teacher expects to be produced from this circuit and we are NOT reading Razavi's book (whatever edition and/or pages you are on, right now.) So we don't have context. We can read the same problem, but without the surrounding context you are immersed within, it's very easy to misinterpret or project our own thoughts onto a situation where that is not appropriate. The problem looks like a DC operating point question. So is the collector current specification the quiescent value? I don't know. Maybe. But if so, why the load value?

Comment: The problem is just an audio amplifier, Razavi's book was just to mention where I got those equations from the chapter of Class AB amplifiers it wasn't to generate any context about Razavi.

Comment: I don't understand the collector current specification. You have a case where the diode voltages and the base-emitter voltages of the BJTs are ***defined*** to be the same. Therefore, the BJTs are forward-biased. But the collector current is a function of the base-emitter voltage. And your specification shows both the collector current and also the base-emitter voltage. That's fine. But this has NOTHING to do with the load, which is also specified. How does the load contribute to solving the resistor values, which is a matter of solving the DC quiescent point? Does it matter?

Comment: Also, your solution for the resistor values looks okay to me for as little as I understand the question. You approached it about the way I would have. If they are wrong, then how so? I've no idea.